# PHP SQL selecting and grouping with no duplicates

Tags: php, sql, select, group-by

I would like to return no duplicate ISBN having the lowest price (see rows in bold). How can I accomplish that?

***isbn     price    supplier***

4000     22.50    companyA

**4000     19.99    companyB**

4000     22.50    companyC

**4001     33.50    companyA**

4001     45.50    companyB

**4003     11.99    companyB**

My query is designed to use **OR** operators. That would be welcome to keep this method.

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE isbn = 4000 OR isbn = 4001 OR isbn = 4003 GROUP BY isbn ORDER BY price;
```

Comment: Since you call it out specifically, it bears mentioning that the `IN()` construct is usually (almost always) more performant for a query like this than the `OR` operator. i.e. for the query above `WHERE isbn IN(4000,4001,4003)` would generally be better.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the `MIN` aggregate function:

```
SELECT isbn, MIN(price)
FROM table 
WHERE isbn = 4000 OR isbn = 4001 OR isbn = 4003 
GROUP BY isbn 
ORDER BY price;
```

Also, as the comment pointed out, using `IN` is probably better for your case than a series of `OR`:

```
SELECT isbn, MIN(price)
FROM table 
WHERE isbn IN (4000, 4001, 4003)
GROUP BY isbn 
ORDER BY price;
```

Comment: I'm gonna use some words, not just integers as ISBN, so I'm curious if IN is gonna cope with that. Anyway, MIN(price) seems to fail in my query. It's not picking up the lowest one. Hmm...

Comment: IN works with any kind of data (of course, accordingly to the type you defined in the column). If your isbn column is a string, IN('123', 'ABC', 'XYZ') will work just as fine.

Comment: I'll keep on testing. For now it looks like MIN is not getting well with IN. It returns the first row as if there was no MIN. It makes no difference.

Comment: There should be no real connection between the two things. Aggregate functions are executed after the where condition, and the where condition should be equivalent whether you use IN or a series of OR. Is there maybe something more to your table and data that you aren't showing in the question, that can cause some difference in behavior?

Comment: Yes, I'm building some complex query. And that would be good to use * instead of all the columns. Now I need to implement the MIN with the following query: SELECT name, id, price, isbn, description FROM book_list WHERE isbn IN($in) AND status = 1 AND stock > 0 AND price > 0  GROUP BY isbn ORDER BY price

Comment: As I see the query selects the MIN price, but it returns a different row than the one the min price belongs to.